# Win32 events vs. condition variables

Tags: multithreading, winapi

I'm writing a [win32 library](https://github.com/FunkyTownEnterprises/Kaptivate) and I need to implement a producer-consumer queue using win32 threads. So far everything is going well, but I'm faced with a dilemma: should I use [events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682655%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or [condition variables](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682052%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to signal to the consumer that something's been added? I've seen examples that can use either one. Personally for my queue I need the ability to wait on multiple signals at once (an *item pushed* signal, and a *quit* signal). There is only one producer and one consumer.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of each? Given my requirements what would you recommend and why? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually reading is implemented as:

```
WaitForSingleObject(evt);   // 1
EnterCriticalSection(&cs);  // 2
//... fetching data from the queue
LeaveCriticalSection(&cs);  // 3
```

But with condition variables (special kind of events) lines 1 and 2 can be replaced
by single call of `SleepConditionVariableCS()` that does 1 and 2 actions atomically.

In high volume cases (frequent R/W operations) this will give you some benefit.

Comment: Note: This does not exist on XP.

Comment: Since he needs to wait on multiple signals at once, WaitForMultipleObjects would be better than WaitForSingleObject.

Comment: Well given that this project does need to run on Windows XP, I guess that makes the choice easy. Thanks!

Comment: BTW: Usually "an item pushed signal, and a quit signal" are combined into single event "queue state changed" or the like.

`bool queue::read(data& d); // returns false if queue was closed
`